# jQuery simple image load

Tags: javascript, jquery

im getting a little issue here. Im trying to load an image, but seems it isnt correct. Im getting the data of image, but i just want to load it instead of.

Whats wrong?

```
var url = $(this).find("img").attr("ref");

$("#produto .main-photo .photo img").load(url, function() {

                    $("#produto .main-photo .loader").fadeOut();
                    $("#produto .main-photo .photo").fadeIn();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `load` for this.  Simply set the `src` of the image:

```
$("#produto .main-photo .photo img").attr("src",url);
```

`load` is used to make an AJAX call.

Comment: Then how can i preload the image?

Comment: Just search for jquery preload images, I'm sure that question has been asked many times.

Answer (score 0):

`$('<img/>')[0].src = yoururl;`

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to just use an `img` tag, dynamically sourced and faded in:

```
var img = $("#produto .main-photo .photo img");
var url = $(this).find("img").attr("ref");

img.fadeOut();
img.attr('src', url);
img.fadeIn();
```